# Nature of the solution $y$ for the ODE $y''-Q(x)y=0, x\in[0,\infty),y(0)=1=y'(0)=1$, where $Q(x)>0$ is a monotonically increasing continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Considering the differential equation $$y''-Q(x)y=0, x\in[0, \ \infty),$$ $y(0)=1,$ and $y'(0)=1$, where $Q(x)$ is a positive monotonically increasing continuous function,

I feel that $y''(x)=Q(x)y(x)$ insists $y(x)$ to blow up as $x \rightarrow \infty$. But how can we arrive at a contradiction for the assumption $1 \leq y(x) \leq M>1$ for $x \in [0,\infty)$? how to use behavior of $y'$ and $y''$ for this dynamic divergence?

OR

how to justify the existence of $K_N \in \mathbb R$ corresponding to any sufficiently large $N \in \mathbb N$ satisfying $y(x)>N$ whenever $x \geq K_N$.

OR

Can we prove $y(x_1)<y(x_2)$ for any $x_1<x_2 \in [0,\infty)$? How to extend the local behavior of $y$ (about the initial point $x=0$) globally to $[0,\infty)$?

Comment: The curve $y$ in the first quadrant is convex, so it is above any of its tangents.

Comment: Sir, How can we show $y''(t)>0$ for all $t \in [0,\infty)$ to say the curve is convex?

Comment: Because if $y(t)>0$ and $y'(t)>0$, then $y''(t)=Q(t)y(t)>0$ and both $y$ and $y'$ will be growing in the point $t$

Comment: Sir, But how $y(t)>0$ for all $t \in [0,\infty)$. I am sure that $y(t)>0,~y'(t)>0$ in a neighbourhood $[0, \delta)$ of $0$. how to extend the behavior of $y''$ to $[0,\infty)$?

Comment: Yes, and in that small interval both $y$ and $y'$ are increasing. So at the end of the interval you find the same situation. There is no turning point, no maximum and no root of $y$ in direction of increasing $t$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that with these conditions that $y$ will be bounded below for all $t$ by $$y_b(t) = 1/2Q(0)t^2 + t$$ which goes to infinity.

$$y'' = Q(x)y$$
$$\geq Q(0)y$$
$$\geq Q(0)$$
the first inequality is justified by the fact that $Q$ is increasing, and the second one is justified by the fact that $y(0)$ = 1, $y'(0)=1$, and $y''(0) >0$.

Comment: Could you pls justify  $y(t) \geq y_b(t)$ for all $t \in [0,\infty)$?

Comment: Please see the edited ansrew @RIYASUDHEENTK

Comment: Sir,  I can see these two inequalities sensible in a neighbourhood $[0, \delta)$ of zero, How to globally extend the concept $y''(x) \geq Q(0)>0$ for all $x \in [0,\infty)$?

Comment: Because $Q(x)$ is monotonically increasing, $Q(x) \geq Q()$.

Comment: Sir, How can we arrive at a conclusion $y''(x)=Q(x) y(x) >0$ from the fact $Q(x) \geq Q(0)$ for all $x \geq 0$? For that we should have $y(x)>0$ for all $x \in [0,\infty)$, right?

Comment: Since at every point $y' > 0$ and $y'' = Q(x)y >0$.

Comment: Sir, How to say ''at every point $t \in [0,\infty)$, $y'>0$''?